# Android Studio : Error building project: Unable to find Gradle tasks to build: [:, :app]. Build mode: ASSEMBLE. Tests: None

Tags: android, gradle

My project has been compiling ok for a long time. But recently Build is failing with following error:

**Unable to find Gradle tasks to build: [:, :app]. Build mode: ASSEMBLE. Tests: None.**

There is also IDE error (Exception in plugin Android):
**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Each request requires the same not null build mode to be set**

I cleaned build folders. Restarted Android Studio.

Gradle Build file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.32'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()

        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.31"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        // Add the Crashlytics Gradle plugin.
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.5.2'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {

        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://www.jitpack.io'
        }

        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2**

Any help will be much appreciated...
Thanks

Comment: Post screenshot of your gradle file